# Print concentric rectangular patterns

Tags: python, programming-challenge, interview-questions, matrix, ascii-art

I am solving interview questions from [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/prettyprint/).

> Problem : Print concentric rectangular pattern in a 2d matrix. The outermost rectangle is formed by A, then the next outermost is formed by A-1 and so on. You will be given number as an argument to the function you need to implement, and you need to return a 2D array.
>
> Example 1: `Input: A = 4.`
>
> ```
>         Output:      
>
>         4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
>         4 3 3 3 3 3 4 
>         4 3 2 2 2 3 4 
>         4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
>         4 3 2 2 2 3 4 
>         4 3 3 3 3 3 4 
>         4 4 4 4 4 4 4
> ```

How can I make this code better?

```
def pretty_print(num):

    m = n = 2*num -1 ##    m x n matrix , length of each row and column
    k = 0 # row start counter
    l = 0 # column start counter
    i = 0 # iterator

    matrix = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]

    while k < m and l < n :  
        #insert the first row
        for i in range(l, n) :      
            if matrix[k][i] == 0:
                matrix[k][i] = num   # row index constt, change values in columns

        k += 1   # first row printed, so increment row start index

        #insert the last column
        for i in range(k, m) :         
            if matrix[i][n-1]==0:
                matrix[i][n-1] = num   # column index constt, change values in rows
        n -= 1   # last column printed, so decrement num of columns

        #insert the last row
        if (k<m):   #  if row index less than number of rows remaining
            for i in range(n-1, l-1, -1):
                if matrix[m-1][i] == 0:
                    matrix[m-1][i] = num   # row index constt, insert in columns
        m -= 1   # last row printed, so decrement num of rows

        #insert the first column
        if (l<n):    #  if column index less than number of columns remaining
            for i in range(m-1, k-1, -1):
                if matrix[i][l] == 0:
                    matrix[i][l] = num # column index constt, insert in rows
        l += 1      # first column printed, so increment column start index

        num -= 1    # all elements of value A inserted , so decrement

    return matrix

print pretty_print(6)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simplify

I find the logic a bit complicated. It could be simpler:

- Loop from -A to +A, let's call the loop variable `n`
- Take the absolute value of `n`
- Generate the values in the row:

  - Loop from -A to +A, let's call the loop variable `m`
  - Use the maximum of `abs(n) + 1` and `abs(m) + 1`

Like this:

```
def pretty_print(num):
    def print_line(n):
        low = abs(n)
        print(' '.join(str(max(low + 1, abs(i) + 1)) for i in range(-num + 1, num)))

    for i in range(-num + 1, num):
        print_line(i)
```

#### Testing

Doctests are awesome, I recommend to use them.
Here's the complete solution with doctests,
you can run this with `python -mdoctest pretty_print.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def pretty_print(num):
    """
    >>> pretty_print(1)
    1

    >>> pretty_print(2)
    2 2 2
    2 1 2
    2 2 2

    >>> pretty_print(6)
    6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
    6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6
    6 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 6
    6 5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6
    6 5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 6
    6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
    6 5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 6
    6 5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6
    6 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 6
    6 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6
    6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
    """

    def print_line(n):
        low = abs(n)
        print(' '.join(str(max(low + 1, abs(i) + 1)) for i in range(-num + 1, num)))

    for i in range(-num + 1, num):
        print_line(i)

pretty_print(6)
```

#### Style

There are some minor style issues with the posted code.
I suggest to follow the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

## without the use of 2-d matrix

```
n =int(input())

for i in range(n):
    temp = n
    for j in range(i):
        print(temp,end='')
        temp = temp -1
    for j in range(2*n-2*i - 1):
        print(n-i,end = '')
    for j in range(i):
        temp = temp+1
        print(temp,end= '')
    print()

for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
    temp = n
    for j in range(i-1):
        print(temp,end='')
        temp = temp -1
    for j in range(2*n-2*i+1):
        print(n-i+1,end= '')
    for j in range(i-1):
        temp = temp+1
        print(temp,end='')
    print()
```

Comment: You should include a short description about how this is an improvement to the original code, and why you chose to do it this way.